# Passing string as an argument in C

Tags: c++, c, unix, pointers

I am having a function:

```
int getparam(char *gotstring)
```

and i am passing a string argument to it, like `char *sendstring = "benjamin"`

Instead of the above declaration I can use,

```
int getparam(char gotstring[])
```

**Question:** Which one is better? And if I have to use `int getparam(char gotstring[])` what are all the other changes I have to make to the existing function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int getparam(char gotstring[])` and `int getparam(char* gotstring)` are identical.  Personally, I would recommend the latter syntax, because it better describes what is actually going on.  The `getparam` function only has a *pointer* to the string; it has no knowledge about the actual array size.  However, that is just my opinion; either will work.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to accept a string argument is

```
int getparam(const char *gotstring);
```

You can then call this using a literal string:

```
int main(void)
{
  int x = getparam("is this a parameter string?");
  return 0;
}
```

Or a character array:

```
int main(void)
{
  char arg[] = "this might be a parameter string";
  int x = getparam(arg);
  return 0;
}
```

The use of `const` on the argument pointer indicates to the caller that the argument is read-only inside the function, which is very nice information.

Answer (score 1):

In this case they mean the same thing, and you do not need to change the remainder of your function. But be aware that in general, arrays and pointers are different things.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is better, really.  It's what you're more comfortable with.  Idiomatically, it is more common to use char *arg instead of char arg[] (think strcmp, strcpy, etc).

Comment: In terms of which one is actually better, I've always felt that the `char mystring[]` syntax as a function parameter is really misleading. It has historically caused endless confusion among inexperienced C programmers who mistakenly believed that the array size information was preserved in the function parameter, and that `sizeof(mystring)` would accordingly return the size of the array, rather than just the size of the pointer. I personally think this syntax shouldn't even be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Since arrays are sent by reference in C both

```
int getparam(char *gotstring)
```

and

```
int getparam(char gotstring[])
```

means the same. **But first one is used more.** So using it makes you a good C citizen.

Comment: I tend to disagree (especially with herd mentality explanation). These constructs are identical for compiler, for human they can (and should I would say) differ semantically: [] indicates passing an array, * passing a pointer to single element.

Answer (score -1):

This is called *passing by reference* and how the name states it means to pass **just a reference** of the variable (in this case a `char*`).

Either solutions will work fine, what will actually happen is that, when `void functionName(char* string)` is called, the address of the first `char` in memory will be saved on stack and passed as a parameter to the function.

Consequently any edit to the variable *inside the function* would edit also the original variable. In this case, since you need to pass an array you just have this option.

For standard types like `int`, `float` you can distinguish them:

```
void passByValue(int i);
void passByReference(int &i);
```

The difference is that in the former case value is copied into stack when calling the function, while in the latter just a reference (pointer) to the value is passed.

Comment: Please I would like to know downvoting reasons, just to understand mistakes and void repeating them. A downvote without a reason is useless, especially for me. Thanks..

Comment: I didn't downvote you so I can't undo it, but presumably the downvoter is annoyed that you are confusing the idea of passing by reference with passing a pointer by value